# How to insert row to any table with calling procedure inside anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, parameters

I called stored procedure inside package in pl/sql. I want to insert a table with this procedure i called. Anonymous block that i create retrieve result on sql developer but not inserting to table related to procedure. Procedure i wrote is like below (Some parameters are out parameters so i didn't put inside executions section).

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
 p1            NUMBER;  
 p2              NUMBER;
 p3                NUMBER;
 p4              NUMBER;
 p5                NUMBER;
 p6                VARCHAR2(200);
 p7        VARCHAR2(200);
 p8        VARCHAR2(200);
 p9       VARCHAR2(200);
 p10           VARCHAR2(200);
 p11           VARCHAR2(200);
 p12           VARCHAR2(200);
 p13                 NUMBER;
 p14            VARCHAR2(200);
 p15            VARCHAR2(200) default 'UNRESOLVED';
 p16               VARCHAR2(200) default null;
 p17           NUMBER default 0;
 p18    NUMBER default 0;
 p19         VARCHAR2(200) default '_';
 p20          VARCHAR2(200) default null;
 p21         VARCHAR2(200) default 0;
 p22          VARCHAR2(200) default '';
 p23          VARCHAR2(200);
  BEGIN
 p3            := 0;
 p4           := 1111111;
 p6             := 'SCADA';     
 p7      := NULL;
 p8      := NULL;
 p9     := NULL;
 p10         := NULL;
 p11         := 0;
 p12         := 'NORMAL';
 p13               := NULL;
 p14          := 'OMS';
 p15          := 'UNRESOLVED';
 p16             := NULL;
 p17         := 0;    
 p18  := 0; 
 p19       := '_';    
 p20       := NULL;   
 p21       := 0;
 p22        := '';   
 p23        := NULL;


PACKAGE.CREATE_RECORD_FOR_TABLE(
  p1 =>     p1,
  p2 => p2,
  p3 => p3,
  p4 => p4,
   ...
   ...
   ...
  p22 => p22
  p23 => p23
 );


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p5 = ' || p5);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p6 = ' || p6);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p4 = ' || p4);


END;
```

Should i add insert into statement in above procedure to insert to table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should simplify it. What are we supposed to do with 23 parameters? Only one would suffice, but - we should see the table, the procedure (which inserts a row into that table), and the way you're calling that procedure. So: one table with one column + one procedure with only one parameter.

Comment: Scalar variables are implicitly null when you declare them, so there is no point in assigning null to them e.g. `p16 varchar2(200) default null;` can be simplified to `p16 varchar2(200);` and `p16  := null;` does nothing (it's already null because no value has been assigned to it). If the whole point of the block is to call one procedure, it seems like delaying and passing 23 variables may be overcomplicating things, unless the procedure uses `out` parameters as they will need a local variable to hold the result. Therefore it all depends on how the procedure is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is building the record for a single table, it would be much cleaner to use `ROWTYPE`. By using `ROWTYPE`, you won't have to define one variable for each column or have to worry about making sure your variable types match the column type. This will also be helpful should there be any changes to the table definition at a later point in time you won't have to define additional variables (or potentially parameters). Using a `ROWTYPE` variable also supports OUT parameters from a procedure if needed.

#### Setup

This is a sample table I created to demonstrate the test case below.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    col1    NUMBER,
    col2    NUMBER,
    col3    VARCHAR2 (200),
    col4    VARCHAR2 (200)
);
```

#### Example

```
DECLARE
    l_table   test_table%ROWTYPE;

    PROCEDURE create_record_with_rowtype (p_table IN OUT test_table%ROWTYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
        p_table.col4 := 'SOMEVALUE';

        INSERT INTO test_table
             VALUES p_table;
    END;

    PROCEDURE create_record_with_parameters (p_col1   IN     test_table.col1%TYPE,
                                             p_col2   IN     test_table.col2%TYPE,
                                             p_col3   IN     test_table.col3%TYPE,
                                             p_col4   IN OUT test_table.col4%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
        p_col4 := 'NEWVALUE';

        INSERT INTO test_table (col1,
                                col2,
                                col3,
                                col4)
             VALUES (p_col1,
                     p_col2,
                     p_col3,
                     p_col4);
    END;
BEGIN
    l_table.col1 := 0;
    l_table.col2 := 1111111;
    l_table.col3 := 'SCADA';
    l_table.col4 := NULL;

    create_record_with_rowtype (l_table);

    create_record_with_parameters (p_col1   => l_table.col1,
                                   p_col2   => l_table.col2,
                                   p_col3   => l_table.col3,
                                   p_col4   => l_table.col4);
END;
/
```